# Issue with Global Variables discord.py

Tags: python, discord

So I'm making a gambling bot in Python for Discord (completely fake money). I have everything the way I want it but I have one issue with my variables. If I put the variable under the on_message function it resets every time you type something. However, making the variable server_money global gets an error every time it's referenced in on_message. How would I go about fixing this so it at least saves every time? A return statement?
Code:

```
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    server_money = 1000
    role_names = [role.name for role in message.author.roles]
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(("!gamble")):
        die_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        die_2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(die_1, die_2)
        if die_1 == 6 or die_2 == 6:
            server_money += 10
            print("You won! You now have: ${}".format(server_money))
            await message.channel.send("You won! You now have: ${}".format(server_money))
        if die_1 != 6 and die_2 != 6:
            server_money -= 10
            print("You lost! You now have: ${}".format(server_money))
            await message.channel.send("You lost! You now have: ${}".format(server_money))
    return server_money
```

I have the run statement, I'm just keeping it private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the global keyword

```py
server_money = 1000
...
async def on_message:
    global server_money
    # Rest of the code
```